# virtualenv not found

Tags: command-line, python3, virtualenv

I just switched from Window 10 to Ubuntu 22.4 LTS

I have installed the virtual env in Ubuntu 22.4 LTS with:

```
pip3 install virtualenv
```

After running that command, I got:

```
*WARNING: The script virtualenv is installed in '/home/harshit/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.*

Successfully installed virtualenv-20.15.1
```

But, when I try to find its version with the command:

```
virtualenv --version
```

I get:

```
Command 'virtualenv' not found, but can be installed with:

    sudo apt-get install python3-virtualenv
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all you installed `virtualenv` a wrong way using `pip`.

Install it by

```
sudo apt-get install python3-virtualenv
```

and all should work correctly.

Regarding the current installation, the warning told you everything. The program has not been added to PATH. That's why you can't run it this way.

You need either add it to PATH, or run it with full PATH:

```
/home/harshit/.local/bin/virtualenv --version
```

Comment: Thank you @Pilot6.  But I have one more thing to clarify and hope you wont' mind to answer it.  So, I have created a new **Standard User** and tried to install the virtual environment again with the command `pip3 install virtualenv` and this time it installed with the message:  *Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable  Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (20.13.0+ds)*  Is this because I have installed it with the  `sudo apt-get install python3-virtualenv` in the main user?

Comment: Now it is not throwing me a **PATH message**, and I able to check its version with `virtualenv --version` and able to activate it with `source env/bin/activate`.